# Replication in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replication, multi-master-replication

Good day! Please tell me how to implement replication in Postgresql as in the diagram. One of the masters need not replicate all of the databases.
[image]

Comment: This is not possible with the built-in replication. You can only have a single master in Postgres. Plus, Postgres' built-in replication always replicates the complete instance (= all databases)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/234246/replication-in-pg-9-between-windows-and-linux-boxes and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Replication

Comment: We generally ask that you try to research the topic before posting, and post if you get stuck while working on the problem. What did you already try? What have you read/investigated?

Comment: You're looking for multi-master replication in PostgreSQL. You might think you need it, but you should find some other way to solve your problem. Multi-master suffers from the limitations implied by the CAP theorem. You can have it consistent, fast, or highly available, but you don't get all three. Latency is a killer for synchronous replication, and asynchronous replication requires a keen understanding of the complexities of multi-master conflicts. Really, it's hard. Don't do this. Solve the problem another way. (There are exceptions, but there's nowhere near enough info here).